# Android Studio File > Settings > Tools > Device File Explorer > Download location path

Tags: android, android-studio

Can anyone tell me what is the original path for this setting?

This would be in deviceFileExplorer.xml and i forgot to copy the path.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `downloadLocation` is specified in the *deviceFileExplorer.xml* file as follows:

```xml
<application>
  <component name="DeviceFileExplorer">
    <option name="downloadLocation" value="$USER_HOME$/.android/device-explorer" />
  </component>
</application>
```